# How do I merge linked list alternately without using nodes? and by using recursion?

Tags: java, merge, linked-list

There are no errors but it still won't work. I can't figure out what's wrong. We still haven't discussed the concept of nodes in class so I have trouble understanding it.

It's output should be:

Skinny Love- Birdy

Happier- Ed Sheeran

Someday- Chelsea Cutler

```
public class HandsOnAct1 {

  static LinkedList songs = new LinkedList();
  static LinkedList artists = new LinkedList();
  static LinkedList playlist = new LinkedList();
  
  public static void Merge(){
      int element= songs.size();
      int number=0;
      
      System.out.println(element);
      
  if (number !=element){
  playlist.add(number, songs);
  playlist.add(number,artists);
  number++;
  
  }
      System.out.println(playlist);
  }
  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        songs.add("Skinny Love");
        songs.add("Happier");
        songs.add("Sometimes");
        
        artists.add("Birdy");
        artists.add("Ed Sheeran");
        artists.add("Chelsea Cutler");
        
        Merge();    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What output are you expecting? As an aside, it's a better design to pass parameters to your `Merge` function instead of having it operate on a fixed set of globals. Return a result and let the caller print so the function is reusable.

Comment: @ggorlen the output should be:

Skinny Love- Birdy

Happier- Ed Sheeran

Someday- Chelsea Cutler

Okay I will try your suggestions. Hopefully I can make it work. Thank you so muchh

Comment: You can edit your post to show that exactly as it should appear on the console. It's rather hard to read as a comment. Thanks. Your code seems like it'd like to use a loop to iterate over the lists but I don't see any loop. Also, it's a good idea to use generics in your lists.

Comment: @ggorlen for this activity, we are challenged not to use loops/iteration and use any recursive methods instead. That's why I'm having lots of trouble ;-;

Comment: That's fine, but you can blow the stack with recursion on a linked list so it's a questionable design choice. Recursion is best when the depth isn't straight linear. If you have to use recursion, you need to call `Merge` from within itself, and here is where you really want/need parameters. I recommend editing your post to state your requirements (that you need to use recursion).

Comment: Okay I will. Thank you so much ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using recursion as i understand it was a pre-requisite?

```
static LinkedList<String> songs = new LinkedList<>();
static LinkedList<String> artists = new LinkedList<>();
static LinkedList<String> playlist = new LinkedList<>();

songs.add("Skinny Love");
songs.add("Happier");
songs.add("Sometimes");

artists.add("Birdy");
artists.add("Ed Sheeran");
artists.add("Chelsea Cutler");

int index = 0;
static void merge() {

    // if you want/need checks
    if ( index >= artists.size()){
        return;
    }

    playlist.add(songs.get(index) + " - " + artists.get(index));
    System.out.println(playlist.get(index));
    index++;
    merge();
}

merge();
```

the main issue with your own code is that you need to call merge again from inside it and either move the index outside the function as i have done or take it in as a parameter like `public static void merge(int index)`. you will then call it from inside like `merge(index++)`.

That's a matter of opinion i guess. (if you want you can read on pure/impure functions and imperative/functional programming which is the difference)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH T^T Now I understand @niclaslindgren. You saved my life today haha

Comment: @ZeyZey I'm glad to hear. Please consider marking the answer as accepted